# JSON reponse from iterate multiple URL to store DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, response

I have dynamic API URL using the which each URL is getting data in response as JSON  which is as following.

```
{
   "@type":"connection",
   "id":"001ZOZ0B00000000006Z",
   "orgId":"001ZOZ",
   "name":"WWW3",
   "description":"Test connection2",
   "createTime":"2018-07-20T18:28:05.000Z",
   "updateTime":"2018-07-20T18:28:53.000Z",
   "createdBy":"xx.xx@xx.com.dev",
   "updatedBy":"xx.xx@xx.com.dev",
   "agentId":"001ZOZ08000000000007",
   "runtimeEnvironmentId":"001ZOZ25000000000007",
   "instanceName":"ShareConsumer",
   "shortDescription":"Test connection2",
   "type":"TOOLKIT",
   "port":0,
   "majorUpdateTime":"2018-07-20T18:28:05.000Z",
   "timeout":60,
   "connParams":{
      "WSDL URL":"https://xxxservices1.work.com/xxx/service/xxport2/n5/Integration%20System/API__Data?wsdl",
      "Must Understand":"true",
      "DOMAIN":"n5",
      "agentId":"001ZOZ0800XXX0007",
      "agentGroupId":"001ZOZ25000XXX0007",
      "AUTHENTICATION_TYPE":"Auto",
      "HTTP Password":"********",
      "Encrypt password":"false",
      "orgId":"001Z9Z",
      "PRIVATE_KEY_FILE":"",
      "KEY_FILE_TYPE":"PEM",
      "mode":"UPDATE",
      "CERTIFICATE_FILE_PASSWORD":null,
      "CERTIFICATE_FILE":null,
      "TRUST_CERTIFICATES_FILE":null,
      "Username":"xxx@xxx",
      "CERTIFICATE_FILE_TYPE":"PEM",
      "KEY_PASSWORD":null,
      "TIMEOUT":"60",
      "Endpoint URL":"https://wxxservices1.xx.com/xxx/service/xxport2/n5/Integration%20System/API__Data",
      "connectionTypes":"NOAUTH",
      "HTTP Username":"API@n5",
      "Password":"********"
   }
}
```

Now catch over here is i have close around 50 URLs which gives this type JSON data. I am iterating it using the following code but i am not able to store in Python pandas dataframe as each response from each URL.
It will be either last response only stored there.

I would also like to convert this whole dataframe to CSV.

What is best method to append response of each result of URL response to dataframe and then convert to CSV?

Python Code as following:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.request import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import urllib.error
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os
import csv

#This CSV file where we are getting ID and iterating over it for each url for get JSON data for the each URL
ConnID_data_read=pd.read_csv('ConnID.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(ConnID_data_read)



user_iics_loginURL='https://xx-us.xxx.com/ma/api/v2/user/login'

headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"

        }


payload = "{\r\n\"@type\": \"login\",\r\n\"username\": \"xx@xx.com.xx\",\r\n\"password\": \"xxxx\"\r\n}"

response = requests.request("POST", user_iics_loginURL, data=payload, headers=headers)
resp_obj = json.loads(response.text)
session_id = resp_obj['SessionId']
server_URL = resp_obj['serverUrl']
print(session_id)
Finaldf = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    api_ver="/api/v2/connection/"+row['id']
    #https://xx-us.xxx.com/saas/api/v2/connection/001ZOZ0B000000000066
    conndetails_url = server_URL+api_ver
    print(conndetails_url)
    act_headers = {
    'icSessionId': session_id,
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",

    }
    act_response = requests.get(conndetails_url.strip(),headers=act_headers)
    print(act_response.text)
    print("Creating Data Frame on this***********************")
    act_json_data= json.loads(act_response.text)
    flat_json = json_normalize(act_json_data)
    print(flat_json)
    Conndf = pd.DataFrame(flat_json)

    Finaldf.append(Conndf)
Finaldf.to_csv('NewTest.csv')
```

Comment: Can you not concat the dfs into a final dataframe adding each new one? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html  Use pandas to write final dataframe to csv.

Comment: Thank you so much your idea for  concat worked like charm awesome thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing I notice is:

```
flat_json = json_normalize(act_json_data)
print(flat_json)
Conndf = pd.DataFrame(flat_json)
```

when you do `flat_json = json_normalize(act_json_data)`, `flat_json` is already a dataframe. Doing `Conndf = pd.DataFrame(flat_json)` is unnecessary and redundant, although shouldn't cause a problem, it's just extra code you don't need.

Secondly here's the issue. When you append the dataframe, you need to set it equal to itself. So change:

```
Finaldf.append(Conndf)
```

to

```
Finaldf = Finaldf.append(Conndf)
```

I'd also just rest the index, as that's just a habit of mine when I append dataframes:

```
Finaldf = Finaldf.append(Conndf).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Other than that 1 line, it looks fine and you should get the full dataframe saved to csv with `Finaldf.to_csv('NewTest.csv')`